# JBOSS 6 _EJB- Transaction Error (Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!)

Tags: jboss

I am getting below exception in jboss 6. its because of when i call 2 diff datasources from my EJB (Local-tx and no-tx). how to solve this as i have to use both tx in my production server.

org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: 
(javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings. 
tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a86889:126a:53f5e358:719e status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >); - nested throwable: 
(org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not enlist in transaction on entering meta-aware object!; - nested throwable: 
(javax.transaction.SystemException: java.lang.Throwable: Unabled to enlist resource, see the previous warnings.
 tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffffc0a86889:126a:53f5e358:719e status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >))

Comment: You must mark an answer correct .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add to your jboss configuration

```
<system-properties>
...
    <property name="com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.allowMultipleLastResources"   value="true"/>
....
</system-properties>
```

or use both XA datasources